# Axios call stuck after using rate limiter to block request

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I'm using rate limiter to throttle my API calls. However, after the rate limiter rejects/blocks, when the time comes for the rate limiter to allows API calls again, suddenly the app stuck inside the Axios call.

Here's an example code snippet. Any help is appreciated.

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const axios = require("axios");

//initialise express
const app = express();

// rate limiter initialize
const { RateLimiterMemory } = require('rate-limiter-flexible');
const rateLimiter = new RateLimiterMemory({
  points: 4, //Maximum number of points can be consumed over duration
  duration: 5, //Number of seconds before consumed points are reset.
});

// Body parser
app.use(express.json());

// Cross origin resource sharing
app.use(cors());

async function test429() {
  var success;    
  var config = {
    method: "get",
    url: "https://www.cloudflare.com/rate-limit-test"
  };  
  await axios(config)
    .then ((response) => {
        console.log("pass");
        success = response.status;
    })
    .catch (async (err) => {
      console.log("failed ", err.response.status);
      success = err.response.status;
    })

  return success;  
}

async function getTest() {
  var index = 0;
  while (index < 100) {        
    await rateLimiter.consume("test", 1) // Consume 1 points
      .then(async (rateLimiterRes) => {
        // Allowed            
        console.log("check API call no ", index);
        const test = await test429();
        console.log("return status : ", test);
        index = index + 1;
        if (test=="429") {
          const toDate = (new Date()).toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace(/-/g, "/").replace("T", " ");
          console.log("error 429 returned, block for 61s since", toDate);
          rateLimiter.block("test", 61); // block for 61sec              
        }        
      })
      .catch((rej) => {
        // Blocked          
        
        
      });  
  }
  console.log("done");
}

getTest();
```